# Required Adobe Flash Player version not installed

Tags: flash-builder, flash, flash-player-11, flashplayer-debug

With Flash Builder 4.7 on Windows 7 / 64 bit and Flex 4.10.0 SDK and [all new files](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air-sdk-download.html) (the new compiler?) under

c:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 (64 Bit)\eclipse\plugins\com.adobe.flash.compiler_4.7.0.349722\AIRSDK\

[image]

I keep getting this error message when debugging a Flex web application:

[image]

And installing (multiple times) [the Windows Flash Player 11.8 ActiveX control content debugger (for IE)](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html) doesn't fix this problem.

Also I've tried to download from the same page and put a new file here:

c:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 (64 Bit)\eclipse\plugins\com.adobe.flash.compiler_4.7.0.349722\AIRSDK\frameworks\libs\player\11.8\playerglobal.swc

At the same time debugging and console work fine.

Does anyone please have an idea, how to get rid of the above dialog?

Comment: What version of Flash Player does [this Adobe page](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/find-version-flash-player.html) detect? For trouble shooting, you might also try to use Chrome or Firefox since those are different plugins than the ActiveX  one.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need here is the 'Projector' debugger, which you can download from here:

http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html:

So, now that we're on 14 and not 11 I guess you want to click on the 'Projector' link http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/14/flashplayer_14_sa.exe or http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/14/flashplayer_14_sa_debug.exe for the debug version.

Then, change directory to:

> C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 (64 Bit)\player\win

Add a directory with the same name as the version you're adding:

> 14.0

Place the newly downloaded file, renaming it like so:

> FlashPlayerDebugger.exe